# Moving single point from curve knowing distance

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, curve

I have a set of x and y points (whatever the function behind) here in black. I would like to move the (x0, y0) point to the (x1,y1) knowing that there is 3 cm (whatever the unit) from (x0, y0) to (x1,y1) at 90° angle.

[image: 1]

I  would like to do it in Python, however obviously this is pretty bad.

```
fig = plt.figure()
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

c = [55,  53, 54]
d = [29,  27,  27]

c = [55,  53 + 3, 54]
dd = [29,  27 + 3,  27 ]

ax.plot(c,d,'-o', c='g')
ax.plot(c,dd,'-o', c='b')
```

**Partial final answer translated into Python (Thanks to picobit), however I would like to make the picobit function "orientation sensitive" :**

```
fig = plt.figure()
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    
    
a = [0.22520001, 0.22140153, 0.21732369, 0.21258711, 0.20764232, 0.20515779,
0.20449048, 0.20467589, 0.20534733]
b = [0.21270538 ,0.21026637, 0.20749939, 0.20383899, 0.19925433, 0.19559762,
0.19440357, 0.19375025, 0.19344115]


dev = [0.0009969 , 0.00143304, 0.00174457, 0.00193148, 0.00199379, 0.00186918,
0.00149534, 0.00087228, 0.        ]

import math

def rotate_vector(x0, y0, angle, dev):
    magnitude = math.sqrt(x0**2 + y0**2)
    xhat = x0/magnitude
    yhat = y0/magnitude
    x_rot = -yhat * math.sin(angle) + xhat * math.cos(angle)
    y_rot = yhat * math.cos(angle) + xhat * math.sin(angle)
    x_rot = x_rot * dev
    y_rot = y_rot * dev

    anglee = 90 # Obviously different if 0 or 45, etc...

    x_rot = (x_rot * math.cos(np.radians(anglee))) - (y_rot * math.sin(np.radians(anglee)))
    y_rot = (x_rot * math.sin(np.radians(anglee))) + (y_rot * math.cos(np.radians(anglee))) 

    x_final = x_rot + x0
    y_final = y_rot + y0
    return x_final, y_final
```

Comment: Is it meant to be at 90 degrees to the original line? You need to do some mathematics. This isn't really a problem with Python.

Comment: Yes indeed at 90 sorry for confusion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136549/calculate-cartesian-coordinates-of-a-point-on-a-perpendicular-of-a-line

Comment: Be careful, you overwrote `c` so its first declaration is useless.

Comment: could you precise: 90° to what ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate cartesian coordinates of a point on a perpendicular of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136549/calculate-cartesian-coordinates-of-a-point-on-a-perpendicular-of-a-line)

Comment: If (a,b) is a vector of length N, then (-3b/N, 3a/N) is the vector of length 3 going in the perpendicular direction to the right of the original vector's direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prerequisites:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_(mathematics)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Your algorithm is:

1. Find the unit vector that points from the origin to `(x0,y0)`
2. Multiply the unit vector by the rotation matrix
3. Multiply this new vector by your desired length (3cm in your example)
4. Move the newly-scaled vector's starting point back to `(x0,y0)`

**Step 1:**
Let `A` be the vector between the origin and `(x0,y0)`. We need to find `|A|`, magnitude of `A`, (aka the length of the line segment) using the Pythagorean Theorem.

Find the unit vector by dividing `(x0,y0)` by `|A|`, giving us `(x0/|A|,y0/|A|)`. This is the unit vector along `A`. Prove it to yourself by drawing a little, tiny right triangle with one end of the hypotenuse at the origin and the other end at `(x0/|A|,y0/|A|)`.

Just to make things easier to type, let `xhat=x0/|A|` and `yhat=y0/|A|`.

**Step 2:**
You can rotate the unit vector by any angle `θ` by multiplying by the rotation matrix. After shaking out the matrix multiplication, you get the new point `(xhat',yhat')` where

```
xhat' = xhat*Cosθ - yhat*Sinθ  
yhat' = xhat*Sinθ + yhat*Cosθ
```

90 degrees is a friendly angle, so this simplifies to:

```
xhat' = -yhat
yhat' = xhat
```

**Step 3:**
Scale the new vector by 3 units (centimeters in your example):

```
3*(-yhat,xhat) = (-3*yhat,3*xhat)
```

**Step 4:**
Move this new vector's starting point back to `(x0,y0)`

```
(x1,y1) = (-3*yhat,3*xhat) + (x0,y0) 
        = (-3*yhat+x0,3*xhat+y0)
```

Those are the coordinates for your new point.

As a quick example, if you have the point `(3,4)`, and you want to perform the same translation as in your example image, then you'd do this:

1. `|A| = 5`, so `(xhat, yhat) = (3/5, 4/5)`
2. `(xhat', yhat') = (-4/5, 3/5)`
3. `3*(-4/5, 3/5) = (-12/5, 9/5)`
4. `(-12/5+3, 9/5+4) = (0.6, 5.8)`

Now prove to yourself that the two points are 3 units apart, again using the Pythagorean Theorem. A right triangle with hypotenuse connecting the two points `(3,4) and (0.6,5.8)` has sides with lengths `(3-0.6)` and `(5.8-3)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot I edited the initial post with Python code.

Comment: One quick question then, if I have some 3D points, how can I take (in plus) the orientation like a rotation matrix ?

Comment: @Acqueux The example that I showed is for rotating a vector with zero z component around the z-axis (aka rotating a vector on the x-y plane), but there are other rotation matrices for rotating a 3D vector around either the X, Y, or X axes (see the Wikipedia article that I linked). If you're wanting to rotate around an arbitrary vector in 3 space, then check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions and Euler's rotation theorem